# Is a block the same thing as content?

Tags: blocks

I'm new to Drupal and I would like to know how to manage content in a block. This is what I understood so far:

- The Drupal page is divided into regions and each region consists of one or more blocks which can be configured in the Appearance/Block Layout page.
- According to my understanding, there are 2 ways to add content:

  1. Directly go to the Content tab and manage the content. However, I do not know into which region(s) this content fits into as I do not see any filter for the region. (I'm assuming they all fall into the 'content' region).
  2. Create a custom block, add the required content into the body and place it in the appropriate region, but this content doesn't appear in the Content tab of Admin page.

I thought that the second way was the way to go, but then what would be the purpose of the Content tab in the Admin page? Also, I read somewhere that blocks are configuration and not content. So what would be the right way to add content? And is it possible to manage content within a region/block through the Content tab?

Comment: Read the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html

Comment: This might also help: https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/structuring-content-drupal-8